# launchSettings.json file opens wrong URL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localhost

When I try I couldn't run this project in my computer today but my teammates can run at their own computer. By the way I can run other projects. My launchSettings file like this:

```
{
 "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
 "iisSettings": {
   "windowsAuthentication": false,
   "anonymousAuthentication": true,
   "iisExpress": {
     "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:4321",
     "sslPort": 0
   }
 },
 "profiles": {
   "IIS Express": {
     "commandName": "IISExpress",
     "launchBrowser": true,
     //"launchUrl": "User",
     "launchUrl": "swagger",
     "environmentVariables": {
       "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
     }
   },
   "Dashboard.WebAPI": {
     "commandName": "Project",
     "launchBrowser": true,
     "launchUrl": "User",
     "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
     "environmentVariables": {
       "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

But when I run this project my url is opening as "https://localhost:4321/swagger/index.html".
I guess this problem is because this url is run as "https" but my applicationUrl is "http".

What could be the cause of this problem?

Edit:
My browser:

[image: error]

Comment: Are you certain that it opens the same port as https? Also please show the whole launchSettings file.

Comment: @M.Radević Yes, I'm sure. I edited. You can see now all file.

Answer (score 1):

Either disable Https redirection in your Startup.cs/Program.cs depending whether you use .net5 or .net6 or put your sslPort value in launchSettings.json to a 4322 port (or some other of your choosing, just not any that are in use) and it'll work.

Edit:

```
{
 "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
 "iisSettings": {
   "windowsAuthentication": false,
   "anonymousAuthentication": true,
   "iisExpress": {
     "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:4321","https://localhost:4322",
     "sslPort": 4322
   }
 },
 "profiles": {
   "IIS Express": {
     "commandName": "IISExpress",
     "launchBrowser": true,
     //"launchUrl": "User",
     "launchUrl": "swagger",
     "environmentVariables": {
       "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
     }
   },
   "Dashboard.WebAPI": {
     "commandName": "Project",
     "launchBrowser": true,
     "launchUrl": "User",
     "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000","https://localhost:5001"
     "environmentVariables": {
       "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Check my edit please. Try that json.

Comment: error: This site cannot establish a secure connection. 
localhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: I tried this json now but the result is same

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed an s in `"http://localhost:4321","https://localhost:4322"`

Comment: I tried again but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

On the Visual Studio toolbar their is a dropdown that allows you to select which profile to run. I suspect you are running the IIS Express profile when you want to run the Dashboard.WebAPI profile. If you see "IIS Express" on your toolbar with a green arrow to the left of it then select the dropdown and choose Dashboard.WebAPI (see mocked up image below)

[image]

Comment: Yes, IIS Express is selected but I get this error today. There was no such error before. I changed as you say but the result is same.

Comment: So you saying that are now running the Dashboard.WebAPI profile but still seeing the Swagger page?

Comment: When I running the Dashboard.WebAPI https://localhost:5000/User opening on the browser.

Comment: I thought that you wanted localhost:5000/User to open. Is that not the case? If not, what do you want to happen when you run the project?

Comment: Normally when I run my project the -http://localhost:4321/swagger url works. It is currently trying to run the -https://localhost:4321/swagger url but cannot run it normally. It shouldn't run with "https" but I'm trying to figure out why it's doing that.